# Can't Open WhatsApp in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

how can I open WhatsApp from my app to a specific number. For Android, the following is working fine

But it didn't work in IOS. Whats App Open and then Show Message 
(This Link couldn't be opened Check the link and try again)

Here is my code for shared Project:

```
 try
 {

   if (await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri("whatsapp://send?phone=+" + mobile)))
       await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("whatsapp://send?phone=+"+ mobile));
   else
       await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new ShowMessagePage("Install Whatsapp", 5000));

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.PushAsync(newShowMessagePage(Helpers.TranslateExtension.Translate("Error"), 5000));

  }
```

-- I Added That in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Just do it like this from your shared code: `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("whatsapp://send?text=Your text"));`

Comment: i want to open whats App with specific number @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("whatsapp://send?phone=xxx));`

Answer (score 2):

Use this code. Works for me in iOS

```
try
{
    Launcher.OpenAsync("https://wa.me/999999999999?text=My%20message");
}
    catch
{

}
```